# Hiccup: How can I render a quotation mark in Reagent?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, markup, reagent, hiccup

I am trying to render quotes around text with Hiccup.

`[:p "I want double quotes around this string"]`

I tried `&qout;` to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try escaping the quotes:

```clj
[:p "\"I want quotes around this string\""]
```